# Load in wp admin assets from child theme

Tags: css, child-theme, admin-css

I started  to create a child theme from a [BoldThemes](https://bold-themes.com/) theme with custom icons. I am able to see icons when edit directly page,

[image]

but when try to edit page from wp admin, I've this issue

[image]

I discovered with DevTools when I try to edit page from wp admin, system don't load assets from child but only from original theme

This is my functions.php

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_parent_theme_file_uri( 'style.css' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_theme_file_uri( 'style.css' ),
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );

?>
```

Other info
WordPress version wordpress:5.9.0-php8.0-apache  ( docker enviroment )

I follow official [documentation](https://boldthemes.ticksy.com/article/12694#3) for create my cutom icons

I copied **admin-style.php** from theme to child and added this line

```
@font-face{font-family:"Chess"; src:url("' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/fonts/Chess/Chess.woff") format("woff"),url("' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/fonts/Chess/Chess.ttf") format("truetype");}
*[data-ico-chess]:before{ font-family: Chess; content:attr(data-ico-chess); }
.bt_bb_icon_preview.bt_bb_icon_preview_chess { font-family:Chess; }
```

and the same for **icons.php**

```
@font-face{  font-family:"Chess"; src:url("' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/fonts/Chess/Chess.woff") format("woff"),url("' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/fonts/Chess/Chess.ttf") format("truetype");
}  *[data-ico-chess]:before{ font-family:Chess; content:attr(data-ico-Chess); }
.bt_bb_icon_preview.bt_bb_icon_preview_chess{ font-family:Chess; }
```

If copy all in original theme work all, but  I want know if is possible resolve this problem with child theme ?